# WordPress RSS/Atom Feed Validation, "Mismatched tag" error

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, validation, feed

We are having trouble getting our feeds to validate on either [Feed Validator](http://feedvalidator.org/) or the [W3C Feed Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/feed/).

When I enter any of the common URI's:

- [siteurl]/feed
- [siteurl]/feed/atom
- [siteurl]/feed/rss2

I get various errors related to mismatched tags, usually either the `</channel>` closing tag at the end of the document, or the `</entry>` tag at the end of a post.

We are using a custom theme, but I can't tell if something there would be interfering. Do I need to escape the inner HTML or close something else?

[Cross-posted.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/217705/rss-atom-feeds-invalid-mismatched-tag-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon closer examination of the output, all of the elements that did not have explicit closing tags were missing the self-closing notation i.e. `<content ... />`;

For some reason the `functions.php` file had these functions to "clean up" the output for HTML5:

```php
/**********************************************
REMOVE SELF-CLOSING TAGS && USER-HARDCODED TAGS
***********************************************/

if ( !is_admin() && ( ! defined('DOING_AJAX') || ( defined('DOING_AJAX') && ! DOING_AJAX ) ) ) {
    ob_start( 'html5_slash_fixer' );
    add_action( 'shutdown', 'html5_slash_fixer_flush' );
}

function html5_slash_fixer( $buffer ) {
    $buffer = str_replace( '<p id="top" />', null, $buffer );
    $buffer = str_replace( ' />', '>', $buffer );
    return $buffer;
}

function html5_slash_fixer_flush() {
    ob_end_flush();
}
```

So I added a check in the `html5_slash_fixer_flush` method to determine if the current query is for a feed: [is_feed (WordPress Codex)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_feed)

```php
function html5_slash_fixer( $buffer ) {
    $buffer = str_replace( '<p id="top" />', null, $buffer );
    if( !is_feed() ){
        $buffer = str_replace( ' />', '>', $buffer );
    }
    return $buffer;
}
```

With this fix, the output validates with warnings only.